# Select and sum from a set of set

Tags: minizinc

I'm new to Minizinc and need some help with the following problem:

let say I have the following sets

```
int: budget= 8;
enum paths = {c1,c2,c3,c4};
array[paths] of int: size=[20,50,90,10];
array[paths] of set of int:colors=[{1,2},{3,2},{4,1,3},{4,3}];
array[paths] of set of int:cost=[{1,2},{10,8},{4,4,4},{50,12}];
array[paths] of var set of int: x;
```

or I can formulate it in the following way

```
int: budget= 8;
enum paths = {c1,c2,c3,c4};
array[paths] of int:size =[20,50,90,10];
enum colors = {w1,b2,y3,r4, h5};
array[colors] of int:cost=[2,10,50,12];
array[paths] of set of colors: s=[{w1,h5},{b2,y3,r4,},{w1,b2},{r4, h5}];

array [paths] of var set of colors: a;
```

So, each path has a fixed size, but I can choose between colors and each color has a cost. So if I allowed choosing one color for each path and then the sum of the cost for all the selected colors should be equal or below the budget.
I know how to select from or sum an array but not from a set of set. Can I get any help, please?

Answer (score 2):

Using the second formulation you can sum over the variable array `a`, and since its elements are sets you can make a sum over those sets, something like this

To pick a color
`constraint forall(i in paths)(card(a[i]) == 1);`

To sum over the chosen colors
`constraint sum(p in paths)( sum(c in a[p]) (cost[c]) ) < budget;`
Since every set contains only one color you are basically just summing the over the array.

**Edit:**
 - Change the definition of a to `array [paths] of var colors: a;`
 - Ensure that you pick a value from the set of options for that path
    `constraint forall(p in paths)(a[p] in s[p]);`
 - Sum over the costs of the variable a `sum(p in paths)( cost[a[p]] ) <= budget;`
The modified code looks like this.

```
int: budget = 20;
enum paths = {c1,c2,c3,c4};
array[paths] of int : size = [20,50,90,10];
enum colors = {w1,b2,y3,r4,h5};
array[colors] of int : cost = [2,10,50,12,4];
array[paths] of set of colors: s = [ {w1,h5}, {b2,y3,r4}, {w1,b2}, {r4,h5} ];

array [paths] of var colors: a;

constraint forall(p in paths)(a[p] in s[p]);

constraint sum(p in paths)( cost[a[p]] ) <= budget;
```

Comment: Actually, this solution select  randomly any color provided  in the main set (enum colors = {w1,b2,y3,r4, h5}; ) it dose not select from the specified set for each color,  for ex, path(c1) can select either  {w1,h5}. Any advice please ?:(